# C#: print out Word document without saving it in advance document.PrintOut()

Tags: c#, ms-word, document

I want to print out a Word document without saving it in advance. Is this possible?

```
//I created an instance for word app  
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application winword = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

//I created a Word document (including pararaphs and tables):
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = winword.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

//I can print the document, if I save it before. But I want to print it without saving the word document.
document.SaveAs2(@"C:\User\\Desktop\Test");
document.PrintOut()

//Export of the document as pdf-file. 
document.ExportAsFixedFormat(label24.Text + "Document" + textBox13.Text, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF, true);
```

Comment: You should be able to print without saving. What happens when you try?

Comment: It doesn't print. Only if the document has been saved before the command document Print.Out() works.

Comment: The code you provide in the question works fine for me - the new document prints with the `SaveAs2` line commented out. Note that it takes a few seconds (noticeable pause) before the job comes through to the printer. If you comment out everything after `PrintOut` so that the code doesn't try to do anything else to Word, does that change anything?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint. I found out the code following the PrintOut-command is the reason. I close the document with document.Close(false,ref missing,ref missing); Probably the document is closed before the print is done. If I set save before close = true it prints. Am I able to make sure the print job is finished before I close the document?

Comment: I added a Thread.Sleep(1000); Now it works. So the reason was the document was closed before the print job was finished. The pause ensures there is enough time the document print job is finished. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that the document is closing before the print job has completed, then the best approach is to turn off background printing, at least for the duration of code execution.

```
winword.Options.PrintBackground = false;
```

Background printing was introduced in order to allow the user to continue working while a print job was processing. This is fine for the user, but a problem for code such as that in the question.