# Delay in MS Word Macro

Tags: vba, printing, ms-word

I'm using macro in MS Word for printing out the document (to virtual pdf printer), saving the file and closing the document:

```
Sub PrintClose()
ActiveDocument.PrintOut Copies:=1
ActiveDocument.Save
If Application.Documents.Count > 1 Then
    ActiveDocument.Close
    Else
        Application.Quit
End If
End Sub
```

The problem is the printed document sometimes is unreadable. It can be opened but the characters are all wrong.

I thought the problem may be that the document closes too soon before the printing is properly executed because when I open the printed document in my virtual pdf printer (PDF24) it is already ureadable. Therefore I suppose the problem is not in the pdf printer but in the printing process. So I was trying to add a delay between printing and closing.

I was only able to make a use of Excels Wait command like this:

`CreateObject("Excel.Application").Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))`

But this command always executes first no matter where I place it. So Word waits for specified time then prints and then closes which doesn't solve my problem.

Is it possible to add delay between printing and closing the document in MS Word? I'm not much skilled in Visual Basic or programming generally.

Comment: Although the following discussion revolves around C#, the reasoning and the code in the "answer" is what you need. Just remove the `;` at the end of the line of code and put `Application` at the front in place of "winword":  [C#: print out Word document without saving it in advance document.PrintOut()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57986509/c-print-out-word-document-without-saving-it-in-advance-document-printout)

Comment: Thank you, it seems to me it should do the thing. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a `DoEvents`? [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function)

```
Sub PrintClose()
ActiveDocument.PrintOut Copies:=1
DoEvents
ActiveDocument.Save
If Application.Documents.Count > 1 Then
    ActiveDocument.Close
    Else
        Application.Quit
End If
End Sub
```

Alternatively, try @Cindy Meister suggestion:

```
Sub PrintClose()
Application.Options.PrintBackground:=False
ActiveDocument.PrintOut Copies:=1
ActiveDocument.Save
If Application.Documents.Count > 1 Then
    ActiveDocument.Close
    Else
        Application.Quit
End If
End Sub
```

Or a 3rd option: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.backgroundprintingstatus)

```
Sub PrintClose()
ActiveDocument.PrintOut Copies:=1
Do While Application.BackgroundPrintingStatus > 0
    DoEvents
Loop
ActiveDocument.Save
If Application.Documents.Count > 1 Then
    ActiveDocument.Close
    Else
        Application.Quit
End If
End Sub
```

PS: Three options here as I'm not able to replicate your issue and therefore can't test it myself...

Comment: Thank you for all the suggested solutions. I will try the @Cindy Meister suggestion first.